# How to split a string into characters of 2

Tags: c

For example Abraham Lincoln into AB, RA, HA ML, IN, CO, LN.
Without using string.h or stdlib.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  printf("Enter the string: ");

  char inputstring[50];
  scanf("%[^\n]", inputstring);

  char *p = inputstring;
  char *k = inputstring;

  while (*p != '\0')
  {
    printf ("%c%c ", *p, *k);
    p++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't changing `k` at all, and aren't changing `p` the correct amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the problem statement, need to:

1. Create a function similar to `toUpper()`.
2. Handle only non-space characters.
3. Handle odd number non-space characters.
4. Formatting, i.e. add `', '` only for non-first pair

Below is the **output sample** of the following code

```
Enter the string: abraham lincoln
AB, RA, HA, ML, IN, CO, LN
```

```
Enter the string: abcde fghijk
AB, CD, EF, GH, IJ, K
```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

char myToUpper(char c) {
    if(c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
        c = c-32;
    } //end if
    return c;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    char inputstring[50] = {0};
    scanf("%[^\n]", inputstring);

    char *p = inputstring;
    int counter=0;
    char firstChar, secondChar;
    int isFirstPair = 1; //this is to handle the flag for first pair, used as the counter for comma character (only first pair do not need comma)
    while (*p != 0) {
        //this is to change between state (1st and 2nd character), need to exclude space
        if (*p != ' ') { //only process non-space character, you can add more character filtering if needed
            if (counter == 0) { //first char
                firstChar = *p;
                counter=1;
            } else  { //if we are on the 2nd character, then capitalize it and print it (along with the comma if needed)
                secondChar = *p;

                if (isFirstPair == 1) {
                    isFirstPair = 0;
                } else {
                    printf(", ");
                } //end else

                printf("%c%c", myToUpper(firstChar), myToUpper(secondChar));
                counter=0;
            } //end else
        } //end if
        p++;
    } //end while

    //this is to handle when there are odd number of non-space characters
    if (counter  == 1) {
        if (isFirstPair == 1) { //this is for the case where there is only 1 character input
            printf("%c", myToUpper(firstChar));
        } else {
            printf(", %c", myToUpper(firstChar));
        } //end else
    } //end if

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright! First I want to say that, there are many corner cases in this problem which must be covered (according to the sample input and output), like:

- Eliminating the spaces even if there are any.
- Capitalizing the characters.
- Putting a comma after each of the paired characters, followed by a space (except the last pair).
- For the last pair there will be just a full-stop and no space after that.
- Also the capability to handle odd-length input (excluding spaces and newline). I am assuming at least one non-space and non-newline printable character will be in the input.

All of these cases are covered in the following implementation. Hope you like it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("Enter the string: ");

    char inputstring[50];
    scanf("%[^\n]", inputstring);

    // THE COMPLETE TASK CAN BE PERFORMED IN 3 STEPS.

    // STEP: 1
    // Remove spaces from the input.
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; inputstring[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(inputstring[i] != ' ')
        {
            inputstring[j++] = inputstring[i];
        }
    }

    // Setting the new termination of the string after a possible removal of spaces.
    // Even if there are no spaces it is still okay. As j is also incrementing.
    inputstring[j] = '\0';


    // STEP: 2
    // Capitalization.
    for(int i = 0; inputstring[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        // If current character in the input string is lower-case,
        // make it upper-case.
        // In ASCII table, the upper-cases [A-Z] are 32 steps behind than their counter lower-cases [a-z].
        if(inputstring[i] >= 'a' && inputstring[i] <= 'z')
        {
            inputstring[i] = inputstring[i] - 32;
        }
    }


    // STEP: 3
    // Initialize two pointers based on even and odd positions.
    // Remember! Counting from 0, hence the 1st position is even
    // and the 2nd position is odd and so on.
    char *even_positioned_pointer = inputstring;
    char *odd_positioned_pointer = inputstring + 1;

    // Print it!
    // As even is behind than odd position (using 0 based indexing),
    // hence, *even_positioned_pointer == '\0' means the string is over.
    // So, looping until it is NOT '\0'.
    while(*even_positioned_pointer != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c", *even_positioned_pointer);

        // It might be the case that the final even_positioned_pointer doesn't have its odd counterpart.
        // This happens when the inputstring's length is odd.
        if(*odd_positioned_pointer != '\0')
        {
            printf("%c", *odd_positioned_pointer);
        }
        else
        {
            // Put a full-stop.
            printf(".");
            break;
        }

        // If the current *even_positioned_pointer is the last character,
        if(*(odd_positioned_pointer + 1) == '\0')
        {
            // then put a full-stop.
            printf(".");
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, put a comma followed by a space.
            printf(", ");
        }

        // To keep the even_positioned_pointer at even position.
        // Same goes to odd_positioned_pointer.
        even_positioned_pointer += 2;
        odd_positioned_pointer += 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not use functiuons. UB if inputstring is a string literal. You modify the given string. IMO very poor code.

Comment: Last string for "abc defg" in only one letter - wrong

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland yes, I know. Please refer to the last point. It is designed to handle odd-length input as well. To pair up distinct consecutive characters like this, you MUST input an even-length string. If you input an odd-length string then the input is technically wrong. So in this case we are free to do anything intuitive. As the input is wrong you cannot hope for a correct answer. You ONLY can say a program wrong when you are inputting the right thing. As nothing mentioned what to do for odd-length input, I'm free to do anything (discard or print).

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland as the spaces are discarded, hence, the input length becomes odd and the input is wrong. If not, please let me know how the program should have outputted for your input "abc defg".

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I modified the input string as the code has no further need of this input. If it was needed, then I would prefer to make a deep copy of it. But I didn't do it as it is an overkill here and modifying the same string will reduce the memory requirement of the program, which is significant for a very large input.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most comprehendible way here would be to write a function which returns you the next character of a string (you may need to skip spaces, so separating this logic into a function will probably be handy), and then just call this function 2 times in a loop until the string ends.

Answer (score 1):

a working solution without extra functions , you can replace len with strlen from string.h later if you decide to.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int len(const char *str){
    unsigned long int i = 0;
    while(1){
        if (str[i] != '\0'){
            i++;
        }else{return i;}
    }
}

int main ()
{
  char string[50];

  printf("Enter the string : ");
  gets(string);
  if( len(string) % 2 == 0 ){
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < len(string) ; i = i + 2){
        printf("%c%c " , string[i] , string[i+1]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your function also doees not work https://godbolt.org/z/Px9xvP

Comment: works on my 32 bit compiler in windows , also gets was dropped in later releases because its classified as a dangerous function and i just wanted to make it simple

Comment: it does not work. it does not ignore whitespaces

Comment: another example when it does not work: https://godbolt.org/z/neTs6j

Comment: The OP didn't state that he want to ignore the whitespaces but i noticed that in the example now gj

Comment: He did in the example

Comment: no if the OP said that he only want a code that work with ignoring whitespaces then its wrong so technically its not :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want.  If you want to create null-terminated arrays with strlen(2), you'll need to make copies.  But if you just want to write the data, you could get away with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        const char *s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "Abraham Lincoln";
        const char *p = s;
        while( p[0] && p[1] ){
                fwrite(p, 1, 2, stdout);
                putchar('\n');
                p += 2;
        }
        if( p[0] ){
                fwrite(p, 1, 2, stdout);
                putchar('\n');
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your function does not work as expected. Is completelly wrong. https://godbolt.org/z/8eqhhx

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I don't understand your complaint.  The link you give shows that it works exactly as expected, splitting the input string into substrings of length 2.

Comment: whe is LN for example (it is required by the OP)

Comment: there are also more possible ways of splitting to two char substrings that you r program shows.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NULL ((void *)0)

char *mystrchr(const char *str, const char ch)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    if(str)
    {
        while(*str) 
        {
            if(*str == ch)
            {
                result = (char *)str;
                break;
            }
            str++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

#define DELIM  " \n\r\t"

void printTwoChars(const char *str)
{
    const char *next;
    if(str && *str)
    {
        //skip leading whitespaces
        while(mystrchr(DELIM, *str)) str++;
        next = str + !!*str;
        while(*next)
        {
            if(!mystrchr(DELIM, *next)) 
            {
                printf("%c%c\n", *str, *next);
                str = next;
                next++;
            }
            else
            {
                next++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "Margareth Tatcher";
    char initials[3];

    printTwoChars(str);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vWPbfz

Comment: Fails on input: " aa" (notice a space in the beginning.)

Comment: Still gives wrong answer for string length > 2. For example try: "aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaa" etc. It only works for string length == 2. Also prints nothing for single character input.

Comment: Also it is preferable to maintain the formatting (capitalization, periods, spacing etc.) as shown in the sample I/O in the question.

Comment: @hafiz031 no you are wrong it works fine. For "abc"  ab and bc are correct two char substrings. Please elaborate why do you think it does not work\

Comment: @hafiz031 Also periods dots and another can be simply added to the DELIM (you decide what you treat as delimiter). Your comment makes not too much sense

Comment: I got your point. But according to the question the split should be disjoint. For input "abc" you are taking "b" twice for making "ab" and "bc".

Comment: @hafiz031 I do not think so. It is simple wrong example. otherwise, it will make no sense for an odd number of characters.

Comment: Yes indeed, we cannot hope for a correct answer from a wrong input. But for even-length input like "abcd" the program doesn't consider taking DISJOINT consecutive pairs. But if you think it is not necessary to be disjoint then it is okay.